# When I tried to remove "Index.php" from codeigniter URL I get redirect to domain.ltd(in chrome)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I tried to make my website's URL cleaner(and SEO friendly) by removing the index.php from my URLs but unexpected results happend, this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs


    RewriteRule ^(site(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

The controller is :site.php.

Comment: "unexpected results happend". Would be nice if you told us what kind of unexpected results happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Three Things To Try:

1. Did you remove index.php from the config.php file
2. Have you tried using the htacces provided from CI directly?
3. Set `$config['uri_protocol']` to be `'AUTO';` OR `QUERY_STRING`

### straight from the user guide:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

> Removing the index.php file
>
> By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:
>
> `example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article`
>
> You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some
>   simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative"
>   method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
> ```
>
> In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php,
>   images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php
>   file.

Comment: Yes, I did this: `$config['index_page'] = '';`